# Spin coherent state path integral derivation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, differentiation, vector-fields, calculus

I'm trying to follow the exposition of spin coherent state path integral presented in [*Condensed Matter Field Theory*](http://www.nucleares.unam.mx/%7Ealberto/apuntes/altland.pdf) by Altland and Simons (section 3.3, Page 134-142), and I have a  problem with the derivation.

Question: In the paragraph under Eq. (3.55), authors write
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B}_{m} = \nabla \times \mathbf{A} = \hat{e}_{r}\,, \quad{} \text{with $\mathbf{A}=\frac{1-\cos{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}}\hat{e}_{\phi}$}\,. 
\end{equation}
I have tried the calculation following the standard formula ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates)) and got a different result,
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B}_{m} = \hat{e}_{r} + \frac{\cos{\theta}-1}{\sin{\theta}} \hat{e}_{\theta}\,,
\end{equation}
where $r=1$ has been set. Then, why the $\hat{e}_{\theta}$ component is abandoned in the textbook?

Comment: Hi @Qamber. Welcome to Phys.SE. Tip: Answers should be in answer boxes; not in the question box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have made a mistake. The $B$ field is purely radial. Did you remember that ${\rm curl} {\bf A}$ is not the same as $\nabla\times {\bf A}$ in any but cartesian coordinates?

To be specific for spherical polar coordinates
$$
{\rm grad\,} \varphi={\bf e}_r \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial r} +{\bf e}_\theta\frac 1 r \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial\theta}+{\bf e}_\phi \frac{1} {r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \phi}\\
{\rm curl\,} {\bf A}=  {\bf e}_r \frac{1}{r\sin\theta} \left (\frac{\partial \sin\theta A_\phi}{\partial \theta}-\frac{\partial A_\theta}{\partial \phi }\right) 
+{\bf e}_\theta\left(\frac{1}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial A_r}{\partial\phi }-\frac 1 r \frac{\partial\, rA_\phi }{\partial r}\right) +{\bf e}_\phi  \frac 1 r \left(\frac{\partial \,r A_\theta}{\partial r}- \frac{\partial A_r}{\partial \theta}\right)\\
{\rm div\,} {\bf A} = \frac 1 {r^2} \frac{\partial \,r^2A_r}{\partial r}+ \frac 1 {r\sin\theta}  \frac{\partial \sin\theta A_\theta}{\partial \theta}+\frac{1}{r\sin\theta} \frac{\partial A_\phi}{\partial z}\nonumber
$$

For  cylindrical coordinates:
$$
{\rm grad\,} \varphi={\bf e}_r \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial r} +{\bf e}_\theta\frac 1 r \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial\theta}+{\bf e}_z \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial z}\\
{\rm curl\,} {\bf A}=  {\bf e}_r \left (\frac 1 r \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial \theta}-\frac{\partial A_\theta}{\partial z}\right) +{\bf e}_\theta\left(\frac{\partial A_r}{\partial z}-\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial r}\right) +{\bf e}_z \frac 1 r \left(\frac{\partial r A_\theta}{\partial r}- \frac{\partial A_r}{\partial \theta}\right)\\
{\rm div\,} {\bf A} = \frac 1 r \frac{\partial rA_r}{\partial r}+ \frac 1 r \frac{\partial A_\theta}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial z}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. However, I still do not understand the sentence, "${\rm curl}\mathbf{A}$ is not the same as $\nabla\times\mathbf{A}$ in any but cartesian coordinates". I want to know in what sense that they(curl and del cross product) are different? Can you give more explanation or provide any reference for that?

Comment: Just compare the equations for $\nabla\times {\bf A}$ in spherical coordinaes with the actual expressions given above and see that they are different!  For details of their derivation you can look at  page 298 in our book: https://goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I find that there should be a factor $r$ in the denominator of $\mathbf{A}$, which is omitted for $r=1$ in this case.
For Eq. (3.54) in the textbook by Altland and Simons,
\begin{align}
S_{\rm top}[\phi,\theta] & = iS \int_{0}^{\beta}\! {\rm d}\tau\, \dot{\phi} (1-\cos{\theta}) \\ 
& = iS \oint_{\gamma}\! {\rm d}\tau\, \dot{\mathbf{n}} \cdot \hat{e}_{\phi} \frac{1-\cos{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}} \\
& = iS \oint_{\gamma}\! \frac{1-\cos{\theta}}{\sin{\theta}} \hat{e}_{\phi} \cdot {\rm d}\mathbf{n} \\
& = iS \oint_{\gamma}\! \frac{1-\cos{\theta}}{r\sin{\theta}} \hat{e}_{\phi} \cdot {\rm d}\mathbf{l} \\
& = iS \int_{\rm surface} (\nabla \times \mathbf{A}) \cdot 
{\rm d}\mathbf{\sigma}\,,
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{A} \equiv (1-\cos{\theta})/(r\sin{\theta})$, which can reproduce the correct result $\mathbf{B}_{m} = \hat{e}_{r}/r^{2} = \hat{e}_{r}$, and the question is solved.